# toolbar menu item click in fragments

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I know this question has been asked and but I am unable to solve my problem after looking at those answer. I have an Activity with a Fragment.
In fragment, I have added the toolbar and I want to handle toolbar menu item click events from the fragments.

In menu, I have added a single share button. I am getting the click event callback for the Up navigation (arrow home button) but I am not getting click event callback for the share button in my fragment.

Can some points me at what I am doing wrong here.

`menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
     tools:context="com.rahul.haridasasampada.details.DescriptionActivity">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_share"
         android:title="Share"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         app:showAsAction="always"           
         app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
 </menu>
```

I have added toolbar to the fragment layout.
My Activity's code -

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Article articleExtra = (Article) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(DescriptionFragment.ARGS_EXTRA);
            DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment = DescriptionFragment.newInstance(articleExtra);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, descriptionFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name_in_kannada);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_description, menu);
        Log.d("debug", "activity : onCreateOptionsMenu");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Log.d("debug","activity: action home has clicked");
                onBackPressed();
                return false;
            case R.id.action_share:
                Log.d("debug","activity: action share has clicked");
                return false;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

My Fragments code -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // some code
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBarActivity actionBarActivity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getView().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    actionBarActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_description);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
            if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_share)
                Log.d("debug","action share has clicked");
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    Log.d("debug", "fragment : onCreateOptionsMenu");
    MenuItem shareMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    mShareActionProvider =(ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareMenuItem);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.d("debug","fragment : action home has clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_share:
            Log.d("debug","fragment: action share has clicked");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View detailFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_description, null);

    return detailFragmentView;
}
```

Comment: why you put ToolBar in your fragment? it is should be in Activity

Comment: I am using a master-detail flow and I have read some where that we should be using toolbar inside the fragments.

Comment: But you `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` to activity, can you?

Comment: @Xcihnegn Yes, I am setting this to the Activity because of the up navigation offered by the Action bar.

Comment: Ok just made a answer for your issue, hope it works

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From Android Docs, for `Fragment`:

> public void  onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
>
> Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You should place your menu items in to menu. For this method to be called, you must have  first called setHasOptionsMenu(boolean).

so you want to control actionbar menu in Fragment, then you have to call `setHasOptionsMenu` method better in Fragment's `onCreate(...)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

also important is that you should not use `inflateMenu` and `onCreateOptionsMenu` both together for same `ToolBar`, `inflateMenu` is for standalone without setting `ToolBar` as `ActionBar`.

**Suggestion:**

keep one `ToolBar` in `Activity` as `ActionBar` for your App, and another `ToolBar` standalone inside `Fragment`.

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes, I have written  setHasOptionsMenu(true); but not working. Please check my full activity and fragment code. Also, it should work without using Toolbar.inflateMenu(). check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511981/toolbar-inflatemenu-seems-to-do-nothing

Comment: what's `Toolbar.inflateMenu()`

Comment: @Xchinegn, this is what mustafasevgi has suggested. Check his answer

Comment: Ok mustafasevgi's solution is for standalone, but if you use standalone then you should not set `ToolBar` as `ActionBar`, right?

Comment: Yes, I have added the standalone toolbar in my fragment completely without using the actionbar at all.

Comment: Suggestion to keep one ToolBar in Activity as ActionBar for your App, and another ToolBar standalone inside Fragment, agree?

Comment: You rock. I searched whole world and this is what solved for me!!! Love you

Answer (score 16):

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_menu:
                //do sth here
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This option is not suitable, once you'll have all the other activities showing the same menu item.

Answer (score 11):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.training1_fragment, container, 
              false);

       setHasOptionMenu(true);

       return v;
 }

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_save : 
       {
       //Write here what to do you on click
        return true;
     }
   }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Comment: Where is break in switch case?

Comment: @ArthTilva `return true;` does the trick. And also, a `return false` is missing before ending the `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

You should getPointer toolbar from your activity class and inflate menu in fragment class.

You can look this ex:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        activity = ((DescriptionActivity ) getActivity());
        Toolbar tollbar=getView.findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_search); 
        activity.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);     

    }



@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:              
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mustafasevgi, but I am using master-detail flow and I want  toolbar for my detailed fragment.

Comment: I have tried this but its not working. Also, toolbar is in fragment right? then why have you written 'activity.toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this); '

Comment: I have made changes in the code(inside the fragment) as you suggested, but its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @RahulChaurasia please can you add full your activity code?

Comment: @RahulChaurasia DescriptionActivity actionBarActivity = (DescriptionActivity ) getActivity();

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511981/toolbar-inflatemenu-seems-to-do-nothing

Answer (score 0):

***Please refer this for click of the Fragment optionMenu click*** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67366798/7370837).