# Menu not working on toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am using `ToolBar` in my app and using menu on it. The menu appears but does not work. I have 4 items in menu, but none of them works. Here's my `menu_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/stop"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Stop"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="About"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and here's the code in my java file

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String url;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String url = "http://softglobe.net/client-projects/rathi-classes/";
    // Request window feature action bar
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
  }
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.stop:
            myWebView.stopLoading();
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Home clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.refresh:
            myWebView.reload();
            return true;

        default:
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

I have made the menu inflate in my java file but still any click is not being handled. Please help me to figure out the solution for this.

Comment: Try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36046456/8089770

Comment: Clicking an icon should throw a nullpointer exception considering you haven't initalized myWebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You don't need to call

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

Second in order to have your toolbar as the actionbar you have to set it as a supportActionBar. So add this lines

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in on create.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I use the toolbar, you have to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` function. Also, remove the `toolbar.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` call from the `onCreate` method.

As I can see from your code, you also haven't set the toolbar as action bar. You can do that by:

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`