# Navigate between fragments using button in toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

In my app, I want the process of creating a new record to be divided into several steps in which users are queried about different information. So I created an activity with `NavHostFragment` and want to use a navigation graph to switch between fragments using a `next` button in the toolbar of this activity.

[image: Clicking the next button navigates to next fragment]

Is it possible to configure the button to navigate between fragments based on a navigation graph? Is this a good approach? Should I rather use a new activity for each step? I am new to android development so I am not sure what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it with your navigation graph

1. Handle toolbar click events in your fragments:

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/30077965/11982611

   While handling each fragment's next button click event implement your navigation code

   ```
   findNavController().navigate(Your action)
   ```
2. Handle all navigation process in your Activity's OnItemOpotionsSelected Listener

   ```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

   val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
   val fragment = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(0)

   when(item.itemId)
   {
       android.R.id.home->super.onBackPressed()
       R.id.next-> {
            if(fragment is Fragment1)
            {
               fragment.findNavController().navigate(Fragment1toFragmen2 action)}

            if(fragment is Fragment2)
            {
               fragment.findNavController().navigate(Fragment2toFragmen3 action)}
       }

       return true
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I tried to handle the navigation in my activity using the ```onOptionsItemSelected ``` method and it works exactly as I wanted. However, when I move from fragment2 back to fragment1 the back button in my action bar disappears and is no more visible only for fragment1. Do you have an idea why? I set it in my activity with ```setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)```.

Comment: It is because the navigation components backstack problem. You need to override onBackPressed method to achieve what you want.